# Adding "Publications (Continued)" in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

[image]
I am writing a CV.  My publication list needs to go onto a second page.  I would like to put the heading "Publications (continued)" at the top of the second page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\moderncvstyle{banking}                           

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
% personal data
\name{jon}{doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{aipsamp} 
\end{document}
```

aipsamp.bib:

```
@PREAMBLE{
 "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}" 
 # "\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%" 
}

@BOOK{Bire82,
   author       = {N. D. Birell and P. C. W. Davies},
   year         = 1982,
   title        = {Quantum Fields in Curved Space},
   publisher    = {Cambridge University Press}
}

@ARTICLE{feyn54,
   author       = "R. P. Feynman",
   year         = "1954",
   journal      = "Phys.\ Rev.",
   volume       = "94",
   pages        = "262",
}

@ARTICLE{epr,
   author       = "A. Einstein and {\relax Yu} Podolsky and N. Rosen", 
   year         = "1935", 
   journal      = "Phys.\ Rev.", 
   volume       = "47", 
   pages        = "777",
}

@ARTICLE{Berman1983,
   author       = "Berman, Jr., G. P. and Izrailev, Jr., F. M.",
   title        = "Stability of nonlinear modes",
   journal      = "Physica D",
   volume       = "88", 
   pages        = "445",
   year         = "1983",
}

@ARTICLE{Davies1998,
   author       = "E. B. Davies and L. Parns", 
   title        = "Trapped modes in acoustic waveguides", 
   journal      = "Q. J. Mech. Appl. Math.", 
   volume       = "51", 
   pages        = "477--492", 
   year         = "1988", 
}

@MISC{witten2001,
   author       = "Edward Witten",
   eprint       = "hep-th/0106109",
   year         = "2001", 
}

@INBOOK{Beutler1994,
   author       = "E. Beutler", 
   editor       = "E. Beutler and M. A. Lichtman and B. W. Coller and T. S. Kipps", 
   title        = "Williams Hematology", 
   chapter      = "7", 
   pages        = "654--662",
   publisher    = "McGraw-Hill", 
   year         = "1994", 

   edition      = "5", 
   address      = "New York", 
   volume       = "2", 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two separate bibliographies with different headings using the [multibib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib) package. This would require splitting your `aipsamp.bib` file into two separate files though. Using `\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}` the reference section headings can be removed and own headings can be used. (Thanks for this good pointer, Howie.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\moderncvstyle{banking}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multibib}
% Second parameter can be anything, as the headings are added separately
\newcites{second}{ }%  \citesecond, \nocitesecond, ...

\name{jon}{doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               

\begin{document}
    % Remove regular reference section headings
    \renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}

    \nocite{*}
    % Manually add reference section heading
    \section{Publications}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{aipsamp}

    \nocitesecond{*}
    % Manually add second reference section heading
    \section{Publications (continued)}
    \bibliographystylesecond{unsrt}
    \bibliographysecond{aipsamp2}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered LaTeX]

Comment: This is a clever idea, though when i tried this with two different .bib files it seems not  to actually grab the second bibliography file but just reprints the first (with the new heading).  Any ideas?

Comment: @Howie Good point, that is indeed not the desired behavior. I've modified the answer to use the multibib package that provides this functionality.

Comment: Great! thank you!!!  One more question if I may:  As you may notice the format of the section headings is different.  I can use:
     \renewcommand{\refname}{\section{Publications}}
and similarly use the section comand in the \newcites line, but this still leaves the dashed line behind?  Any thoughts?  Also, and interesting behavior of multibib seems to be that it includes the whitespace in the .bib file in the final document.  Easy enough to fix manually but seems odd never-the-less

Comment: I found the answer to the headings problem elsewhere.  Inserting:
    \renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}
into the body of the document removes the headings.  Headings can then be manually added.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Good idea! I've edited my answer to reflect your final solution.